# Having trouble working if statement comparing strings and reading user input

Tags: if-statement, user-input, equals

I have a String stored as "word" (from another method) and want to compare it to the user input stored as String "guess". The progam prints out as needed and lets the user input but it doesn't read the input it seems. When the correct word is entered it still contiunes to go to the default on the switch case until the "i" value reaches 0 then it prints that case. I understand this may be a simple fix but I have Spent all night on this and would appreciate any help.

```
   String word = chooseRandomWord(words);

   int i = scrambledWord.length();
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(i + " Points: What is your guess?");

    String guess;
    guess = input.next();

    if (guess.equals(word)) {
        System.out.println("Congragulitions! your score is " + i + " points");
        System.out.println("the word was " + word);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    if (!guess.equals(word)) {
        while (i >= 0) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("sorry the word was " + word);
                    System.exit(0);
                default:
                    i--;
                    System.out.println(i + " Points: what is your guess?");
                    guess = input.next();

            }
        }

    }
    else {
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each execution of

```
guess = input.next();
```

in the switch/case block, there's no checking whether the correct word was entered. As it is now, even if the correct word was entered the program just keeps looping until variable i reaches zero, all the while doing nothing with the received guesses.

Comment: I see what you are saying. once the if is checked it isn't checked agaim. So if I changed the if statements to  "while" that should handle that correct?

Comment: If you're suggesting to just change occurrences of the keyword "if" to "while", then no, that won't fix it. There are many ways to do this; you could simply copy-paste this block

`if (guess.equals(word)) {
        System.out.println("Congragulitions! your score is " + i + " points");
        System.out.println("the word was " + word);
        System.exit(0);
    }`

to right after the `guess = input.next();` statement in the switch/case block.